# Get TSQL Hierarchy Path

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Code w/ my try

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
    (
        [Id]        BIGINT
      , [Value]     NVARCHAR(MAX)
      , [Parent_Id] BIGINT
    ) ;
INSERT  @T
VALUES
    ( 1, N'A', NULL )
  , ( 2, N'B', 1 )
  , ( 3, N'C', 2 )
  , ( 4, N'D', 1 )
  , ( 5, N'E', NULL )
  , ( 6, N'F', 5 )
  , ( 7, N'G', 5 )
  , ( 8, N'H', 7 ) ;

; WITH [CTE] AS
    (
        SELECT  [Id]
              , [Value]
              , [Parent_Id]
              , CAST ( [Value] AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS [ValuePath]
        FROM    @T
        --WHERE   [Id] = 3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  [P].[Id]
              , [P].[Value]
              , [P].[Parent_Id]
              , CAST ( CONCAT ( [C].[ValuePath], N' > ', [P].[Value] ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS [ValuePath]
        FROM    @T    AS [P]
        JOIN    [CTE] AS [C]
        ON      [P].[Parent_Id] = [C].[Id]
    )
SELECT      *
FROM        [CTE]
ORDER BY    [CTE].[Id]
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 ) ;
```

Current Output

```
Id  Value   Parent_Id   ValuePath
1   A   NULL    A
2   B   1   B
2   B   1   A > B
3   C   2   B > C
3   C   2   A > B > C
3   C   2   C
4   D   1   D
4   D   1   A > D
5   E   NULL    E
6   F   5   F
6   F   5   E > F
7   G   5   E > G
7   G   5   G
8   H   7   H
8   H   7   G > H
8   H   7   E > G > H
```

Desired Output
When no filter

```
Id  Value   Parent_Id   ValuePath
1   A       NULL        A
2   B       1           A > B
3   C       2           A > B > C
4   D       1           A > D
5   E       NULL        E
6   F       5           E > F
7   G       5           E > G
8   H       7           E > G > H
```

With Filter (e.g. Id = 3 )

```
Id  Value   Parent_Id   ValuePath
3   C       2           A > B > C
```

Goal
To get the path of Value field with " > " delimiter. There can be an optional Id filter to be applied. I'm getting all records, but only need 1 record for each Id and its complete path. Also, performance is important. Would you recommend I create a udf with the filter? Please let me know if you need more info. I'll

Comment: This is the third or fourth question on this very topic today and all of them have looked incredibly similar. Must be a homework assignment.

Comment: haha, for real? It's too funny.
p.s. not a hw assignment. :)

Comment: It is funny how questions like these go in cycles. But yes, the sample data, output and even the > delimiter have been the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your query to this returns your desired output:

```
;WITH [CTE] ([Id], [Value], [Parent_Id], [ValuePath]) AS
(
    SELECT [Id], 
           [VALUE], 
           [Parent_Id], 
           [Value]
    FROM @T
    WHERE [Parent_Id] IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [n].[Id], 
           [n].[Value], 
           [n].[Parent_Id], 
           CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), [CTE].[ValuePath] + ' > ' + [n].[Value])
    FROM @T [n] INNER JOIN [CTE] ON [n].[Parent_Id] = [CTE].[Id]
)
SELECT * 
FROM [CTE]
ORDER BY [Id]
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad for a quick reply. It works almost the way I need it to work. The only thing that's missing is if I want to filter by Id (e.g. Id = 3), it doesn't return the path properly. I tried to pass it into the 1st/2nd select inside the cte, but not getting quite what I need. Thanks again.

Comment: If you add "Where Id = 3" to the final select it returns EXACTLY what you stated you want. The only change I would make would be to get rid of all those [ and ]. They are just noise that make this difficult to read.

Comment: Yea, I thought about adding it outside the CTE, but that affects the performance (filtering after getting all the data). Is there an easy way to filter within the CTE to improve performance (actual table has quite a few records)?